# How could the text field show the value stored in the `paramsText` when the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a `HashMap<String, String>` in Struts2:

```
@In(scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Out(scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
private Map<String, String> paramMap;
```

and a `String[]`:

```
@In(scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@Out(scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
private String[] paramsText;
```

the `paramsText` is used to store the `value` of `paramMap`, and in my jsp, I use `<s: iterator>` to display the `paramMap` and `paramsText`:

```
<s:iterator value="paramMap" var="param" status="paramsStatus">
<tr>
 <td>
 <input type="checkbox" key_id="<s:property value="#paramsStatus.index"/>" name="params" value="<s:property value="#param.key"/>"
 <s:iterator value="params" var="app">
  <s:if test="#app==#param.key">
  checked
  </s:if>
 </s:iterator>/>
 &emsp;<s:property value="#param.value"/>
 </td>

 <td>
 <input type="text" text_id="<s:property value="#paramsStatus.index"/>" name="paramsText" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

How could the text field show the value stored in the `paramsText` when the checkbox is checked? I'm thinking about the `value` property, how should I specify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the `paramsText` you can get while iterating. You need to use [`<s:set>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/set-tag.html) to store the value in the value stack.

```
<s:iterator value="params" var="app">
  <s:if test="#app==#param.key">
  checked
  <s:set var="paramsText" value="#param.value"/>
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>/>

<input type="text" text_id="<s:property value="#paramsStatus.index"/>" name="paramsText" value="<s:property value="#paramsText"/>">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide, this solves the problem, but what if `paramsText` doesn't store the `value` of `HashMap`, instead it stores the text inputted by users, how to show the value in this case?

Comment: You can prevent the user to modify the value via setting `readonly` attribute or use the input `hidden` type.

Comment: Actually, my logic is: if the user doesn't input text, the `value` of the `HashMap` will be stored, if the user input some text, the text will be stored instead of the `value`